# Wrap SQL Server Objects Quickly?

Tags: sql-server-2008, iis, slashdb

Back in the MSSQL 2000 timeline, there was an IIS integration layer that allowed HTTP GET commands to make select statements, and there were other SqlXml niceties that worked (not that fast or well but they worked) out of the box. I gave a chance to expose database stuff fairly quickly.

What is the comparable technology for MSSQL 2008/2012? I saw slashDb (http://www.slashdb.com/) and it seems to do that, but I am trying to understand the other options out there.  Just SQL Server crud and sproc access.

Thanks.

Comment: I represent the company that produced /db. If you still would be interested in giving it a try, just contact us via website or chat me up on Twitter @agilevic.

Comment: SlashDB has come a long way since your question. Try it again.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, SlashDB does exactly that and more. Full disclosure: I am the founder and CEO.

Once SlashDB is installed you would use its web interface to connect it with your database. Depending which database login and database schema you use for that connection, you will have the tables and views from that schema turned into of URL endpoints.

Those URLs can be followed in the browser but they are also API endpoints in JSON, XML or CSV. It works for reading and writing (you can control that in user configuration).

In addition to that you can define a set of parameterized SQL queries. Each query is given a name and instantly becomes an API endpoint too.

In order to help you getting started easily SlashDB is available on AWS and Azure marketplaces, as a Docker container from DockerHub, pre-built virtual machines or as .rpm and .deb packages for installation directly on Linux.

For more technical info please visit: https://docs.slashdb.com

Answer (score -1):

The nearest equivalent may be SOAP/HTTP endpoints, however Microsoft has [deprecated them](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280436%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for [various reasons](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldenengine/thread/c5e75052-3a63-45c7-b234-f4d55dea8b67/) and recommends WCF or ASP.NET instead. Although the simplest way to get a quick CRUD setup is probably to use a framework or ORM that generates it for you, like [LINQ to SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386976.aspx) or whatever else suits your needs.